# jQuery DataTables filtering by external properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I have a data table being generated from the values of a Backbone model. But I would like to implement filtering based on the model attributes instead of the values displayed in the table, as often the latter are human-readable version of the same attributes which are useless or harder to process than the original attributes.

I am looking for an efficient a way to expose the backbone model used to generate a row (as an object) to the filtering API so I can filter by custom model attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery DataTables uses term [Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) which means that the same attribute may contain different values for display, sorting, filtering and type detection.

You can use [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#object) option to define which property would be for display and which for filtering/sorting. For example:

```js
"columns": [
    "data": {
        "_": "phone",
        "filter": "phone_filter",
        "display": "phone_display"
    }
]
```

It means that data property `phone_filter` is used for searching, `phone_display` for display and `phone` for all other purposes (type detection, ordering).

See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data) for more details and demonstration.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you help me on a related [DataTables question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066590/jquery-datatables-data-filter-not-working). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to [Gyrocode.com's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961327/6838451).
It is possible to use data-* attributes like this:

```
<td data-search="YourBackboneModelField">human-readable text</td>
```

[documentation here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)