# data-filter not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

According to the [DataTables Orthogonal Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) manual page you can use `data-search` and `data-filter` HTML5 attributes to specify custom filtering terms to be used instead of the display data.

That doesn't seem to be the case. Though there is some specific behaviour in my app - I am using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) and passing it an unrendered [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement).

I also tried implementing a [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function with very little success. The custom filtering data specified in it is not used by the [`.filter()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()).

Below is the implementation as requested:

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    targets: '_all'
    render: ( data, type, row, meta ) =>
      if type == 'filter'
        return 'test'
      else
        return row[meta.col]
  }
]
```

My custom filter looks simply as this:

```
table.data().filter ( value, index, context ) ->
  console.log [value, index, context]
  return true
```

But I am only getting the original table values and no custom filtering attributes.

Any ideas about what could be improved?

Comment: There is no such thing as a HTML5 data attribute called data-search or data-filter. Is that a datatables thing? To answer my own question: Yes it is.

Comment: Please share you `columns.render` implementation.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I updated the question.